# pass data between controllers (service) angular

Tags: angularjs, service, pass-data

I'm creating a quiz and I want to add the answer the user gives to an array (myAnswers), when the quiz is finished, I redirect my user to the summary page, where he can see the correct answer and the answer he has given. Those are both different controllers. I tried experementing with a service, but this doesn't work out...

Can someone help me with this one please?

## service

```
var lycheeServices = angular.module('lycheeControllers', [])

lycheeServices.service('myAnswerService', function () {
var myAnswers= [];
this.AddAnswer = function(number, a){
    myAnswers[number-1] = a;
};
this.getAnswer = function(number){
    return myAnswers[number-1];
};
});
```

## controller quiz

```
lycheeControllers.controller('quizCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'myAnswerService',
function ($scope, $http, myAnswerService) {


$scope.checked = function (answer) {
        myAnswerService.addAnswer(number, answer.answer);
    }
```

## controller summary

```
lycheeControllers.controller('summaryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'myAnswerService', function ($scope, $http, myAnswerService) {

$scope.myAnswer = myAnswerService.getAnswer(number);
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller summary, when you retrieve a value using your `myAnswerService.getAnswer(number);`, it returns a new value and your `$scope.myAnswer` is a **copy** of the value.

If your answer is a value type, any changes on it **will not affect** the value in your service answer array.

If your answers array contains objects (reference type), then manipulating the **properties** of `$scope.myAnswer` will update the properties of **the same object** referenced by the answer inside the service's array. But if you replace it with **another answer**, your answer inside the answers array will not notice the change

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but a sensible solution is you store the service object to the scope. Like this:

```
$scope.myAnswer = myAnswerService
```

**Note:** When you do redirects, ensure that you don't do **full page refresh** because your data will be cleared completely.

Comment: I want to show the answer that has been given on that question (number) in my summary. So get the answer out of the array myAnswers

Comment: @Warri: please check my updated answer. BTW, what did not work out for you exactly?

Comment: It works already, I just forget to add my service to my app module. Thanx for the help anyway!

Comment: @Warri: You should answer the question and accept it yourself or delete this question. Otherwise, this question will remain unanswered.